# On websocket event I'm trying to slice an array inside an associative array of object but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, associative-array

I have an objects containing property playerData which can look like this for example:

```
this.playerData = {"username1":{"hand":["AD,"JD","2D","3H"],"points":0}}
```

on a websocket event I'm running a function trying to slice the hand array like this.
GAMES_LIST[gameId] = associativ array where key is id and value is instance of object constructor.
handIndex is a number which is an integer.

```
socket.on('event',function(data){
 GAMES_LIST[data.gameId].playerData[data.someUsername].hand.slice(data.handIndex,1);
});
```

The slice doesn't work and the array is unaffected. When I do it outside the function
like this it works.

```
var game = gameConstructor(some params...);
game.playerData[someUsername].hand.slice(handIndex,1);
```

Getting no errors. Gone through everything rigorously but can't seem to find the problem. Had to leave out a lot of code that would be to complicated to get a grasp of quickly but have simplified that which is relevant. Would greatly appreciate some help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `slice` doesn't affect the array, ie doesn't remove items, it just returns the items in the range of the specifed indexes. Are you meaning to use `splice` which removes and returns the items in the range of the specified indexes?

Comment: @PatrickEvans thank you there we have it! Can't believe it was that simple after all this time spent on this problem... I will be forever grateful!